# RMSE for sift algorithm

Tags: matlab, sift

I work with the **vl_sift** algorithm. How can I calculate **RMSE** to match two images? second image is projective transform to the first image.

```
I1 = imread('filename');
T = projective2d([0.89   1.24  0.002; 
              -0.95  1     0.0025;
              0      0     1]);
I2 = imwarp(I1(400:800,400:800),T);
```